# Update edge attributes of a graph with networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have the following graph with the edge attributes:

```
import networkx as nx
import random
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge('x','a', dependency=0.4)
G.add_edge('x','b', dependency=0.6)
G.add_edge('a','c', dependency=1)
G.add_edge('b','c', dependency=0.3)
G.add_edge('b','d', dependency=0.7)
G.add_edge('d','e', dependency=1)
G.add_edge('c','y', dependency=1)
G.add_edge('e','y', dependency=1)
```

After setting the structure of my graph, I will sample three different edge attributes and multiply them with a random number as followed:

```
for i in range(3):
    sampled_edge = random.sample(G.edges, 1)
    print(sampled_edge)
    sampled_edge_with_random_number = G.edges[sampled_edge[0]]['dependency'] * random.uniform(0,1)
    print(sampled_edge_with_random_number)
```

Now I want to update the initial graph attribute with the new sampled graph attribute so it would look something like this. The algorithm should look for the same edge attribute in the structure and update the dependency value:

```
for i in G.edges:
    if i == sampled_edge:
        i['dependency'] = sampled_edge_with_random_number
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just access the attribute to update and change it

```
>>> G=nx.DiGraph()
>>> G.add_edge('x','a', dependency=0.4)
>>> G['x']['a']
{'dependency': 0.4}
>>> G['x']['a']['dependency'] = 10
>>> G['x']['a']
{'dependency': 10}
```

Another approach is [nx.set_edge_attributes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes.html)

```
>>> sampled_edge = ('x', 'a')
>>> new_val = 42
>>> nx.set_edge_attributes(G, {sampled_edge:{'dependency':new_val}})
>>> G['x']['a']['dependency']
42
```

where `('x','a')` is your `sampled_edge`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but is there an algorithmic way of doing it? So that the code looks for the matching edge and then updates it?

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I nedded. If I transfer it for my code, I will get the following error message though:
```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: UPDATE: I guess it has something to do with difference between lists and tuples. Because the output of random.sample is "[('x', 'a')]"

Comment: I solved the error message by implementing the following:
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, {sampled_edge[0]:{'dependency':new_val}})